# При запросе telebot показывает ошибку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps


city = ''
message = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot("***")

# Кнопки

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    itemhelp = types.KeyboardButton('/help')
    itemweather = types.KeyboardButton('/weather')
    markup.add(itemhelp, itemweather)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери команду:'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Ты можешь у меня узнать прогноз погоды на сегодня, просто напиши команду: "/weather"')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    if message.text == '/weather':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В каком городе хочешь узнать погоду?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_city)

def reg_city(message):
    global city
    city = message.text

    # Уникальный ключ API для получения информации с сайта 'ОpenWeather'

    owm = OWM('***')
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()

    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    w = observation.weather

    # Характеристика погоды

    temperature = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    temperature2 = w.temperature('celsius')['temp_max']
    humidity = w.humidity
    speed = w.wind()['speed']

    # Подсказки как одеваться в зависимости от температуры воздуха

    if temperature >= 10 and temperature <= 15:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Можешь одеваться чутка свободнеe!')
    elif temperature >= 0 and temperature <= 9:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Одевайся тепло, на улице холодно и следи за ветром. Он коварный.')
    elif temperature >= -10 and temperature <= -1:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Не ну это пипец, очень тепло одевайся, можно лего заболеть.')
    elif temperature >= 16:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Ух ты, на улице очень тепло, одевайся как хочешь.')

    #вывод погоды:

    bot.send_message(message, f'В городе {city} сейчас: {temperature} градусов, максимальная температура: {temperature2} по Цельсию, {humidity} % влажности, Скорость ветра: {speed} М/С.' )
    

bot.infinity_polling()
```

[image: Ошибка]

Ошибка в том, что после запроса /weather и ввода города выдает ошибку с api bot'а, пересоздавал ключ но бесполезно.

Comment: Попробуй вместо `bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'В каком городе хочешь узнать погоду?')` сделать `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В каком городе хочешь узнать погоду?')`

Comment: В конце у вас вообще `bot.reply_to(message, ...`, там же тоже какой-то `id` должен быть наверняка, а не просто `message`?

Comment: @oleksandrigo поменял как и подсказал но ошибка все такая же, уже совсем не понимаю что делать. Проект уже завтра надо сдавать а тут такое(

Comment: @CrazyElf в документации у библиотеке так говорят писать, а так оно работает без id

Comment: Просто прикол в том, что я его около полумесяца не трогал. Все работало до этого. Вот решил его проверить и вот тебе раз, поменял токен бота и api ключ owm но как понимаете безрезультатно

Comment: Ну я бы всё же посоветовал попробовать единообразную посылку сообщений везде сделать для начала. Либо через `chat.id`, либо через `from_user.id`, либо через `bot.reply_to(message,`, но чтобы везде было одинаково, во всём коде. Опять же у вас ещё и `bot.send_message(message,` используется, это уже четвёртый вариант. Нельзя так код писать )  Я собственно этот четвёртый вариант и имел в виду, не оттуда код скопировал. Он наверняка неправильный, обратите внимание на него!

Comment: @CrazyElf я тут запускал отдельно код вывода погоды, и он выдал ошибку api ключа. Сейчас полный скрипт выдает совершенно другую ошибку... так же с api ключом. Жесть какая то... (https://ibb.co/gy1TKjX)

Comment: наверное что то с самим сервисом не то